# Desenvolvimento Asp Clássico: COM, como usar?

Tags: asp

Gostaria de uma explicação a respeito de componentes COM, O que são exatamente? Como usá-los? Pelo que entendi eles são uma espécie de biblioteca que fica no servidor dai voce associa ao seu projeto.

Estou trabalhando com manutenção e criação de código em ASP clássico, usando VBScript, gostaria de saber uma maneira mais eficiente de trabalhar com a tecnologia do que copiar o código ja feito de outros sistemas para fazer um novo. Meu intuito é criar(classes ou componentes, não sei dizer o que preciso ao certo) para que a criação e novas funcionalidades ou sistemas seja mais ágil reutilizando os códigos ja feitos.

Answer (score -2):

Exemplos:

[Interoperabilidade com componentes COM](http://www.linhadecodigo.com.br/artigo/2131/por-dentro-da-base-classe-library-capitulo-12-interoperabilidade-com-componentes-com.aspx)

[Usando componentes COM ja existentes](http://www.linhadecodigo.com.br/artigo/309/voce-tem-componentes-com-e-quer-aproveita-los-em-net.aspx)

[Criando componentes COM](http://imasters.com.br/artigo/15184/c-sharp/criando-componetes-com-vb6-em-c/?trace=1519021197&source=single)

[Passo-a-passo criando um componente no VB](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/151w6x12(v=vs.120).aspx)

[Criacao de um controle ActiveX (COM)](http://imasters.com.br/artigo/4318/linguagens/como-criar-um-controle-activex-control-para-o-vb6/?trace=1519021197&source=search)

---

**COM:**
A tecnologia Microsoft COM (Component Object Model) permite que os componentes de software se comuniquem. O COM é usado por desenvolvedores para criar componentes de software reutilizáveis, unir componentes para criar aplicativos e aproveitar os serviços do Windows.

Objetos COM podem ser criados com uma variedade de linguagens de programação. As linguagens orientadas a objetos, como C, fornecem mecanismos de programação que simplificam a implementação de objetos COM. A família de tecnologias COM inclui COM, Distributed COM (DCOM) e controles ActiveX®.

Mais sobre:
https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model

Comment: Exemplo de uso:
http://www.macoratti.net/com_vb.htm